# Use custom header for material datepicker where Material version < 6 and Angular version < 6

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Here is a snippet from my `package.json`, just to show you the version of packages we use in our project.

```
"@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "5.0.4",
"@angular/common": "5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "5.2.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "5.2.0",
"@angular/material": "5.0.4"
```

If you see, we are using Material 5.0.4

The problem is that, in Material 5.0.4 Date-Picker, there is no way where we can customize the header.

I need to add the following in my Material Date-Picker:

1) A title : "Select a date"
2) A close button

Now by reading the documents, I can see that Material Version 6 has this feature where we can create a custom header component and pass it to the mat-datepicker.

You can see the example here: [Material Datepicker custom header example](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/datepicker-custom-header/datepicker-custom-header-example.ts)

To upgrade to Material v6, I need to upgrade Angular core to V6 as well, which is not feasible for us at the moment.

I need to know, if anyone has done this earlier or has any way where the header can be customized without changing the datepicker core.

Any ideas/directions will be appreciated.

Thanks.